# Как создать автоматически таблицы для SQLite?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, entity-framework

После создания создаёся пустая база данных

`context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();`

Перед добавлением нужно создать тыблицы в БД но EntityFramework не создаёт для SQLite

`context.AAA.Add(aaaaaaa);`

```
public class Context1 : DbContext
{


    public DbSet<AAA> A{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<BBB> B{ get; set; }

    public Context1() :
        base(new SQLiteConnection()
        {
            ConnectionString = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder() { DataSource = @"C:\bin\Debug\Database1.sqlite", ForeignKeys = true }.ConnectionString
        }, true)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

Comment: Покажите класс вашего контекста

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что таблицы не создаются автоматически? При попытке добавления сущностей, возникает какое-то исключение?

Comment: В SQLite не создаются автоматически. Ошибка при добавлении чего-либо в БД. БД пустая.

Comment: так слишком сложно как предлагают https://gist.github.com/flaub/1968486e1b3f2b9fddaf

Comment: Провайдер SQLite может не поддерживать Code First генерацию таблиц, в этом случае вам надо вручную выполнять их генерацию чистым SQL.

Comment: Ах, у вас EF6? (не core?) Помню, он не умел создавать таблицы для SQLite. Точно. Неужели до сих пор не исправили? В EFCore такого, вроде, нет

Comment: Посмотрите это: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29460684/6766879

Comment: Выполлняйте запрос(ы) на создание таблиц вручную. `create table ...` и т. д. Делайте это один раз при установке приложения. Или добавьте в запрос `if not exists`, если программа может запускаться без установки. [документация](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать пакет [SQLite.CodeFirst](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.CodeFirst/). На гитхабе есть примеры использования для этого пакета: https://github.com/msallin/SQLiteCodeFirst